# Unity mobile touch control

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I have been experimenting with creating a 2d brick breaker game in Unity where the ball is controlled by a paddle along the bottom. I can move it in the editor using the keyboard but I wanted to experiment this on an Android mobile and wanted to know how I can drag the paddle left/right using touch/finger control.

I played around with a few c# scripts I found online but the problem I have with them is the movement isn't sharp enough and the movement lags a bit. Just wanted to see if anyone knows of a good solution to move objects around using touch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is :

```
void Update(){
    Touch[] touches = Input.touches;
    if(touches.Length > 0){
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(touches[0].position.x, 
                                  paddle.transform.position.y, 
                                  paddle.transform.position.z);
        paddle.transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

This script just gets the array of touches on the screen, then sets the paddle xPos to the xPos of the first finger that touched the screen. Thus, if two fingers or more are touching the screen, only the one that touched it before the others is considered by the script.